# This program to convert infix to postfix in c is giving a runtime error.why?

Tags: c, stack, postfix-notation, infix-notation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char stack[50];
int top=-1;

void push(char x)
{
    stack[++top]=x;
}

char pop()
{
    if(top==-1)
        return -1;
    else
        return stack[top--];
}
```

This function is used to prioritize operators:

```
int priority(char x)
{
    if(x=='+'|| x=='-') {
        return 1;
    } else if(x=='(') {
        return 0;
    } else if(x=='*'||x=='/') {
        return 2;
    } else {
        return 3;
    }
}

int main()
{   
    char exp[50], *e, x;
    scanf("%s", exp);
    e = exp;
    while(*e != '\0') {
        if(isalnum(*e)) {
            printf("%c",*e);
        } else {
            while(priority(stack[top]) >= priority(*e)) {
                printf("%c",pop());
            }
            push(*e);
        }
        e++;
    }
    while(top!=-1) {
        printf("%c",pop());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting a runtime error in this program. I have no idea why. Can u suggest to me any changes I can implement? In some compilers I get the output as some infinite loop.

Comment: Which error do you get ?

Comment: Try using a debugger to see where it getting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The first time this code is executed

```
while(priority(stack[top])>=priority(*e))
```

the value of `top` is `-1` so you access `stack[-1]`. That is not a legal access and your program may crash.

If the program doesn't crash, you'll get some "random" value that you pass to `priority`. Now you compare the priority of this "random" char to the priority of the first char of the input. Let's assume the comparison result in true. Then you execute:

```
printf("%c",pop());
```

Since `top` is `-1`, the `pop` function will not change `top` so it stays at `-1`. Then you again do:

```
while(priority(stack[top])>=priority(*e))
```

Since both `top` and `*e` hasn't changed, the comparison will again result in true. In other words - an endless loop.